# How to edit result of "for + tab" shortcut in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I write "for" and click tab in Visual Studio (2019), the IDE generates this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

But I want the IDE to generate this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

}
```

How to move open curly bracket one level up in code generation?

Comment: Standard C# is written with the curly braces below the for statement.

Answer (score 3):

From the `Tools` menu, select the `Options` command. In the pop-up that appears, expand the `Text Editor` item in the list on the left hand side, as follows: `Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting` and select the `New Lines` item.

Then, in the list displayed, scroll to find the `Place open brace on new line for control blocks` item and *uncheck* that, as shown here (a preview of the format style will be shown in the lower part of the pop-up):

[image]

Click on the `OK` button, and you're done.